# Using Geokit and Geocoding to print value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geokit

I have a Model Stop as such.

```
 class Stop < ActiveRecord::Base
    geocoded_by :address
    after_validation :geocode
    acts_as_mappable defaults_units: :kms, lat_column_name: :latitude, lng_column_name: :longitude
```

My stop table has field `id,name,address,longitude,latitude`

This table contains pre-populated data of some bus stops.
I have a small form where the user enters an address.

```
<%= form_tag("/welcome/index", method: "post") do %>
  <h5>Current Location</h5>
  <%= text_field_tag :address %>
  
  <p>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
  </p>


<% end %>
```

Then in my controller i capture this address entered by user and use [GEOKIT](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails) to find the bus stop that is closest to the user provided address as such.

```
curAddress = params[:address] 
@curlonglat = Geocoder.coordinates(curAddress)
@answer = Stop.closest(origin: @curlonglat)
```

Finally i try to print the stop that is the closest in my view file as such

```
<% if @answer%>
<%= "#{@answer} "%>
<% end %>
```

My output is `#<Stop::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007faa485228e0>`

I am not sure what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `@answer` is a instance of `ActiveRecord_Relation:`, so it looks you have to do it like this

```
<%= @answer.first.address %>
```

Comment: when i do answer.name it prints simply Stop which is not correct

Comment: try `@answer.first` and `@answer.inspect` what that gives you ?

Comment: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Stop id: 18, longitude: nil, latitude: nil, name: nil, created_at: "2015-04-24 00:57:46", updated_at: "2015-04-24 00:57:46", address: "Random University">]>
 
So appaeantly it is pulling out the wrong ID which means something is wrong with my geokit....

Comment: As it looks, `<%= @answer.first.address %>` works. But as you told that wrong ID is coming, watching that. best of luck.